# AWS Lambda function not saving on VPC selection

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I cant save my Lambda (Node.js)function on AWS with VPC selection, its not saving at all and did not get any message from AWS.
When I try to save without VPC selection its working but then I select VPC its not saving at all.

[image]
Its always showing same status save.

When I click on this, its not saving after refresh its again back to the previous form.

Comment: Are you selecting two "private" subnets?

Answer (score 20):

This happens most of the time when the role you have configured for lambda does not have access to the VPC. There is an error appearing at the top of the screen under the Designer tab, but it is difficult to catch and not always visible.

[image]

To resolve this, modify the role you have configured in lambda to include the policy named  "AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole". Then you will be able to save this function.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html

Comment: This is the solution. And another way to catch this error if designer tab is minimize, is when you click save, the button still appears *active* (When you save something the button in lambda inactivates unless you make another change).