# Cannot save lambda handler function in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I having uploaded my lambda_function.zip file on Amazon S3 bucket and am trying to use this (using the Code entry type - 'Upload a file from amazon S3' to test my lambda function.
When I am trying to save this and then test, it is not saving. The output I get on testing is:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
}

This is the default output when I make no changes on the code entry type (default: Edit Code Inline) which shows that my action (of trying to use the S3 bucket .zip file) is not getting saved.

Please help.

I have already successfully created and tested a few lambda functions using the same method of using the S3 bucket before, but am suddenly facing this issue where its not getting saved

Note1: The size of the zip file (containing the .py file and some python libraries) is around 180 MB

Note2: I have not used any VPC, and hence this question [AWS Lambda function not saving on VPC selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55760149/aws-lambda-function-not-saving-on-vpc-selection), does not solve my problem.

Comment: What is the size of extracted contents ? It should be < 250 MB, and that should be allowed. See https://hackernoon.com/exploring-the-aws-lambda-deployment-limits-9a8384b0bec3

Comment: @TechFree Thank you for pointing it out. The size of the extracted content exceeds 250MB. I want to include the following python libraries in the deployment package for my python code (with the lamda_handler function) to run:
Pandas, numpy, requests, nltk, gensim
(The pandas and numpy packages together take about 180MB which leaves only 70 MB space as per the 250 MB limit for other libraries)
Is there any way I can include all the libraries mentioned above within 250 MB?
If not, what can I do to use AWS Lambda to deploy my model?

Comment: Recommend to break down the logic into multiple lambda ( make modular), or deploy on EC2 ? and invoke via Lambda..?

Comment: @TechFree How do I call one lambda function from another or use the output of one lambda function in another?